# MS Excel: Finding the earliest date on a row of mixed content

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Does anyone know how to get the earliest date on a row in Microsoft Excel. There is not a predictable number of columns on each row, and there are values other than dates which need to be ignored. It could be done with Excel formulas or VBA.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Right now I am using this quick and dirty VBA function, but when I loaded new input data (approx 200 rows by 100 columns) a message box came up saying that Excel does not have enough resources to process my changes.

```
' returns smallest date on row
Public Function getSmallestDateFromRow(r As Integer, sheetName As String) As Date
    Dim toReturn As Date
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim scanToColumn As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim tmp As Variant

    Set rng = Sheets(sheetName).Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious) 'is this inefficient?
    scanToColumn = rng.Column
    toReturn = #12/12/2100#

    For c = 1 To scanToColumn
        tmp = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(r, c).Value
        If (IsDate(tmp)) Then
            If (toReturn = Null) Then
                toReturn = tmp
            ElseIf (toReturn > tmp) Then
                toReturn = tmp
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    If (toReturn = #12/12/2100#) Then
       toReturn = 0
    End If

    getSmallestDateFromRow = toReturn
End Function
```

Comment: Is this a Worksheet function/UDF? or a function called by another macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that Excel (and many other Microsoft products) store dates as floating-point numbers:

- The integer part is the count of days elapsed since January 1st, 1900 (e.g.: 1 is equivalent to 1/1/1900)
- The decimal part is the 'fraction' of day elapsed (e.g.: 0.5 is equivalent to 12:00 pm)

The question on how to find a minimum or maximum date value is then obfuscated by the fact that you may have many other numbers in your row. So you have to define first a "valid rank" for the dates. After that, a simple "array formula" can do the trick:

**Example.** Let's say your valid range is between January 1st, 2000 and December 31st, 2100. Then your valid "number rank" is:

- 1/1/2000 is equivalent to 36526
- 12/31/2100 is equivalent to 73415

Now you can write the function to track the minimum date value within this range:

```
function trackMinimum(rowRange as range) as date
    on error resume next
    dim j as integer, minValue as date
    dim t0 as double, t1 as double
    dim ans as date

    t0 = cdbl(dateserial(2000,1,1))
    t1 = cdbl(dateserial(2100,12,31))
    ans = 0
    for j = 1 to rowRange.columns.count
        if ans = 0 then ' You need to store the first valid value
            if rowRange.cells(1,j).value >= t0 and rowRange.cells(1,j) <= t1 then
                ans = rowRange.cells(1,j).value
            end if
        else
            if (rowRange.cells(1,j).value >= t0 and rowRange.cells(1,j) <= t1) _ 
               and rowRange.cells.value < ans then
                ans = rowRange.cells(1,j).value
            end if
        end if
    next j
    trackMinimum = ans
end function
```

Of course I am assuming that the `rowRange` parameter is a single row range.

Hope this helps you

---

By the way, the `isDate()` function is not "fail safe": It must take a valid expression (text) to detect if it is a date or not, and that may depend on formatting. That said, you may prefer to use `isDate(.cells(r,c).Text)' instead of`.value`, since the`Value` property may return a double or floating-point value that can be evaluated as "not a date".

Comment: This is not an array formula... there's no need for that. Of course, this function needs to be "copied" on each row. Or another function or sub can evaluate this formula for every row in a given range